# Socket.IO acknowledgement vs event emitting

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to build application (to be more accurate a library for my personal projects) which will be based on room management (lobby, matchmaking, rooms, etc).

I managed to do it with socket.io.

Now, my question is, I don't know what kind of design pattern should I use.

I noticed that socket.io has ack callbacks, which surprised me and think it's good, but I'm not sure what's the difference between sending back ack with parameters or emitting an event with parameters.

So, question is, what's the pros and cons using acks over emitting an event and vice-versa?

Let's say, what's the pros and cons using following codes:

assuming handler callback is `fn(err, res);`

**acknowledgement style:**

```js
socket.on('join', function (data, ack) {
  // do the joining stuff here.
  return ack(null, { response: 'goes_here' });
});
```

versus

**event emitting style:**

```js
socket.on('join', function (data, ack) {
  // do the joining stuff here.
  io.to(client_sid).emit('join_response', null, { response: 'goes_here' });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, there is not a real difference if you only think about the ping-pong thing. I would the notable changes is that it allows you to validate a specific event has been acknowledged (although you could argue that you can also do that with a `_response` event by passing an event id), and provides a more convenient way to handle responses, by using a simple callback style notation: the first example looks way cleaner and simple.

Besides, it allows you to avoid creating two event keys for just one type of event which is kinda repeating. Acknowledgement has been made for this purpose, so there is no real reason not to use it in favor or creating another event.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering if ack responses had a `different meaning` but if it works fine, then all good and it's all I wanted to know.

Comment: What if the connection is bad and the message doesn't send to the other part, will ack be called then ?